# Is there any way to detect dialect automatically?

Tags: mandarin, cantonese, topolect

For current task I need to create a solution how to detect if some video or audio of Chinese speech is  Mandarin or Cantonese (for now I do not need others dialects).

For example, there is almost 100% solution to search for radio/TV in USA/Honk Kong or others locations where Cantonese is main dialect. Canada doesn't work due it has 50/50 for Mandarin/Cantonese. For Mandarin is simpler, just search sources from Mainland China.

But there is also another part - YouTube videos. I didn't find a way to detect dialect of speech in video. Auto-subtitles shows only text version which is in Simplified Chinese (written).

Also, there was an idea about searching for -p, -t or -k endings in speech (due Mandarin does not have them any more). I think it is quite good solution but not the best - others dialects have them too.

So my question is - Do you know or maybe have an idea how to detect Cantonese/Mandarin dialect in speech video automatically or using subtitles? 
Maybe there is a list of Mandarin/Cantonese only characters?

Comment: Write your own supervised learning machine learning algorithm on samples of audio data.

Comment: @droooze this is an option, best one so far haha (even that it requests a lot of boring work), but I was wondering about some easiest way. And the best way to do it ask someone who actually know Chinese

Comment: Detect dialect automatically  would be another exciting challenge for AI after it conquered Go.

Comment: If it's common speech, it's fairly easy, as the colloquialisms, common terms and sentence patterns do not overlap much. e.g. usage of 系 in Cantonese and 是 in Mandarin; 边度 in Cantonese vs 哪里/哪儿 in Mandarin; 儿化音 in Mandarin that simply does not exist in Cantonese; characters like 喇,咁,哂 etc in Cantonese which do not exist in Mandarin whatsoever; 不 in Mandarin vs 唔 in Cantonese; usage of English words with Chinese grammar e.g. "gua唔guarantee" in (HK-style) Cantonese vs 包不保证 in Mandarin, and so on and so forth. I hesitate to call them dialects, they really are much closer to different languages.

Comment: @dROOOze I think machine learning would work. Here are some Mandarin sources on YouTube, [China Central TV - International Channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCnAsZ46UTeFEgwOEwMezngQ), [China Central TV - Variety Show Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/entcntv), [Hunan TV](https://www.youtube.com/user/imgotv), [Zhejiang TV](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC52EYUUSlzcYqHj-qsx0RHg), [Shanghai TV](https://www.youtube.com/user/kankanews). Here are some Cantonese sources on YouTube, [TVB](https://www.youtube.com/user/tvb), [RTHK](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC6of7UYhctnYmqABjUqzuxw).

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways for this to work, each could have varying degrees of difficulty in implementation.

---

### Word Choice

As @Marko mentioned in comments, Cantonese usually has a very different choice of word for common expressions. For example:

- [點](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%BB%9E#Etymology_2)(trad.)/点(simp.) in Cantonese vs. 怎 in Mandarin
- [邊](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%82%8A#Etymology_2)/边 vs. 哪
- 係/系 vs. 是
- 唔 vs. 不
- 嘅 vs. 的
- 喺 vs. 在
- 咁 vs. 这么

sentence-final particles:

- 咯 (Cantonese only)
- 咩 (Cantonese only)
- 啫 (Cantonese only)
- 㗎 (Cantonese only)
- 吗 (Mandarin only)

This will be easier to implement **if the subtitle is an exact transcription** of what's being said (I say this because sometimes they are not, instead, they are in written/more-Mandarin form). Frequency analysis of the appearance of these syllables could also be possible, I guess? **Note**: they work better on casual conversations than formal speeches or readings of written material.

This Wiktionary [category page](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:Cantonese_language) could be a gem if you decide to use this approach, but not every entry in this category is Cantonese-specific.

---

### Tones

I'm thinking of a pitch analysis. And Cantonese has more tones - 9 in total - than their Mandarin counterpart - 5. If you can devise a way to count the total tones used in the audio, or to match each syllable to a tone and see which model fits best, it could be possible to tell the two apart.

---

### Other phonetic features

Other distinctions exist, to name a few:

- 儿化(Erhua) in Mandarin (actually I'd not call them standard Mandarin, but northern Chinese dialect)
- the -p, -t, -k, -m sound in Cantonese

However, I'm not sure if/how you can detect them automatically.